# How can I objectively measure our home-office network quality/speed?

Tags: networking, router, internet, packet-loss, stress-test

We run a couple of serious businesses from home. My net topology is this:

[image: Net topology]

- Guest computers get addresses from `net1`
- Work computers from `net3`
- The firewall forbids any incoming request from `net1` to be forwarded to `net2` or `net3`.
- `net2` and `net3` are allowed to do outgoing connections to internet and both are "routed" via NAT thru the ip-tables in the firewall into `net1` so they can find the fiber router to go out.

## Problem

- We are feeling in the last months that there's a bad internet connection.
- Some pages "slow loading". Sometimes it's better to disconnect the Wi-Fi and use mobile data and it seems faster.
- We cannot do streaming (needed for some of our business).
- We cannot even do a `docker push` (needed for some of our business) if any layer is over 100MB because it resets the connection at mid-way and starts over infinite times.
- Some websites that load in 100ms in other homes or offices are sometimes loading in 1 or 2 or even 5 seconds.
- Those failures are being experienced in all 3 nets (ie: if net1 was super-fast and nets 2 and 3 super-slow, it's clear it'd be the firewall, this is not the case, it's all slow).

## Nevertheless

Fiber is 100 Mbps

If I do the Ookla speed-test it says "it's all okey at 100Mbps" both upload and download:

[image: download speed]
[image: upload speed]

Also, if I do pings, I don't see packet-loss and ping time is abut 10-15ms approx:

[image: pings 100% received]

If we call the ISP (in this case Movistar in Spain), they test the fiber and it says it is "working perfect" and if we call them again unnecessarily because it works, they are going to bill us the man-hours of coming to test that nothing fails.

### But... there are problems! We are suffering those problems, indetectable by speedtest, ping and the fiber-provider.

As said: I can't do a streaming with ObsStudio. I can't do a `docker push` with large layers, etc.

Note: If you are tempted to say "reboot", thanks. I could already think about that. Rebooting router, firewall PC, client laptops, etc. It's all tested. It's not about rebooting.

## So... Question

I want to test somehow the "network quality" at every point of the network:

- In cable `net1`
- In cable `net2`
- In cable `net3`
- In wi-fi `net1`
- In wi-fi `net3`

Same way `memtest86+` is "the tool" to **acid-test a memory** in a PC by writing lots of patterns in the memory cells or `badblocks` linux command is "the tool" to **acid-test the blocks on a hard disk** by reading and writing many patterns, I wonder...

What is "the tool" to really **acid-test the network** by reading/writing lots of different patterns (ie: many different types of packets, tcp, udp, large, small, sequenced, non-sequenced, round-times in ms, etc.) from/to the network?

## Final notes

Anyone thinking to answer "hey, do not use wifi, use cable", save the answer:

We have another similar setup in another building and the **very same wi-fi devices** go ultra-fast (via wi-fi) in the other building. It's not about "avoid wi-fi". It's about "checking what's happening with measured data", not intuition.

The question is **not** how can I improve performance in my wireless devices, but **how can I measure net performance numerically.**

Comment: "The tool" is **Iperf**, but it might not be a simple run-and-find-issue tool. See some info here https://iperf.fr/

Comment: The more systems you put on a wireless network the worse it becomes. That degradation is exponential, not relative. Connect everything by wire and leave wifi to short term connections.

Comment: Thanks Yisroel, will investigate.

Comment: Thanks Bib. Maybe I forgot to tell that we have another similar setup in another location and the **same** devices in the other building go super-fast. I'll edit the question to clarify. So it's not the "amount of devices" nor "the fact that they are wireless", because in the other building they go max-speed. All together. The question is *not* how can I improve performance in my wireless devices, but *how can I measure* performance numerically.

Comment: @Xavi Montero On what host in your network you measure speed?

Comment: @Xavi Montero Check what going on with PMTU discovery, MTU settings and blocked ICMP replies. https://serverfault.com/questions/162062/how-to-check-who-blocks-icmp-during-mtu-path-negotiation    https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/25885-pmtud-ipfrag.html

Comment: I can measure the speed at any of those hosts. Majorly linux boxes so I can run bash commands. I can also measure in some windows or android devices if needed.

Comment: About "whats going on with PMTU discovery, MTU settings and blocked ICMP replies" => For ICMP replies I guess you mean launch a ping for a while and see the drop ratio. Pings do not drop packets. For PMTU and MTU I'd need help in understanding how do I measure them.